# How to combine and filter final dataframe based on origin dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the following .csv files saved in a directory:

```
foobar_label1.csv
foobar_label2.csv
foobar_label1+.csv
foobar_label1++.csv
foobar_label3.csv
foobar_label2.csv
goodcat.csv
```

These .csv files got the below format:

```
|            time         ||    field1    ||    field2    ||    location    ||    gbps    |
|-------------------------||--------------||--------------||----------------||------------|
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    abcdef    ||    Barcelona   ||    15      |
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    234343    ||    fdsfsf    ||       London   ||    10      |
| 2019-08-15 13:55:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    abcdef    ||    Barcelona   ||    20      |
| ....................... ||    ......    ||    ......    ||    .........   ||    ..      |
| 2019-08-15 14:00:00 UTC ||    132131    ||    casdas    ||    Barcelona   ||    80      |
```

All those files are under the same folder. So what I want is to get all files that start with foobar, create dataframes from them and then combine into 1 bigger dataframe that will contain all their data.

Here's the trickier part:

`For every duplicate time and field2 and location` I want to remove the duplicates and keep 1 of that row where the field1 and gbps would be the ones from one of the labels, based on hierarchy.

Example, I got the following 3 labels: "mansion", "house", "hut" with descending importance.

If `2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC` with the same `field1` and `location` exists 5 times in the combined dataframe just because it existed in the files (foobar_mansion.csv, foobar_house.csv, foorbar_hut.csv, foobar_mansion+.csv, foobar_house+.csv), so in the combined dataframe we would see something like this:

```
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    potato    ||    Barcelona   ||    15      |
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    tomato    ||    Barcelona   ||    30      |
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||     apple    ||    Barcelona   ||    05      |
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    carrot    ||    Barcelona   ||    70      |
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    banana    ||    Barcelona   ||    20      |
```

I want to keep only 1 row of these data, either:

```
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    potato    ||    Barcelona   ||    15      |
```

or

```
| 2019-08-15 13:45:00 UTC ||    123456    ||    carrot    ||    Barcelona   ||    70      |
```

because those came from the "mansion" label file.

So there needs to be a way as dynamic and automated as possible for the combined dataframe to remember that "label" and use it as described.

I hope I explained it as best as possible. My brain is burning. Do you have any code to look at or suggestions on how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set up a way to sort your file names.  That way, you ensure that the appropriate labels come first and consequently, `drop_duplicates` will keep the first rows which will be the ones you want.

I'll also use `pathlib` to grab the appropriate files.

**note** `pathlib` is Python3.  Use `pathlib2` for Python2

```
from pathlib import Path
mydir = Path('path/to/your/dir')

priority = {
    'mansion': 0,
    'house': 1,
    'hut': 2
}

def key(x):
    k = ''.join([y for y in x.split('_')[1].split('.')[0] if y.isalnum()])
    return priority.get(k, float('inf'))

def read_csv(fh):
    """I stubbed out this function if we need to modify the data import step"""
    return pd.read_csv(fh)

cols = ['time', 'field2', 'location']
df = pd.concat(map(read_csv, sorted(mydir.glob('foobar_*.csv'), key=key)))
df = df.drop_duplicates(cols)
```

---

Alternatively, you could embed the file labels into the dataframe itself.  Subsequently sort and drop duplicates.

---

#### Response to Comment

You can rearrange the `key` to be a function that returns a function

```
from pathlib import Path
mydir = Path('path/to/your/dir')

def get_key(p):
    def key(x):
        k = ''.join([y for y in x.split('_')[1].split('.')[0] if y.isalnum()])
        return p.get(k, float('inf'))
    return key

def read_csv(fh):
    """I stubbed out this function if we need to modify the data import step"""
    return pd.read_csv(fh)

priority = {
    'mansion': 0,
    'house': 1,
    'hut': 2
}

cols = ['time', 'field2', 'location']
df = pd.concat(map(read_csv, sorted(mydir.glob('foobar_*.csv'), key=get_key(priority))))
df = df.drop_duplicates(cols)
```

Comment: hey, I understood what you wrote and I am trying to make it work. I get `ValueError: No objects to concatenate` though. Any ideas on that? And I tried to print the filenames inside the `mydir.glob('foobar_*.csv')` and it prints them alright. Does the map() function expect an object and not a list or something? Also if I don't need to modify the data can I just `pandas.concat(map(pandas.read_csv, sorted(my_path_lib.glob(regex_concat_filename), key=key)))`?

Comment: Hmm.  Can you paste the a snippet of the actual csv file?

Comment: Hey @piRSquared, unfortunately I can't, but I figured it out. I had edited your key function to take 2 arguments(filename and priority) and that had messed things up. It makes sense too. If I don't want to have the key function inside the same block as the priority, what can I do? I set the dictionary as global inside the key so I don't have to put it as an argument but I don't like it, although it works. Any suggestions? Nevertheless I like that answer, thanks a lot!